# Default CRI implementation and default CNI implementation in K8S

Tags: kubernetes

Recently I am looking at the knowledge of CRI and CNI.
What are the default CRI implementation and default CNI implementation in K8S?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Regarding the [CRI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/container-runtimes/) the most common are:

   - Docker
   - CRI-O
   - Containerd

The most 'default' one being Docker.

2. Regarding the [CNI](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/compute-storage-net/network-plugins/):

> Network plugins in Kubernetes come in a few flavors:
>
> - CNI plugins: adhere to the appc/CNI specification, designed for interoperability
> - Kubenet plugin: implements basic cbr0 using the bridge and host-local CNI plugins

Currently [Calico](https://docs.projectcalico.org/introduction/) is the only CNI plugin that the kubeadm project performs e2e tests against. You can find more info about installing a Pod network [here](https://docs.projectcalico.org/introduction/).

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: If I deploy kubernetes in private cluster, do I need to manually configure CRI and CNI？

Comment: If you create your cluster with `kubeadm` than normally you don't have to configure anything, just install them. For example I have recently created a 3 node cluster with Docker as my container runtime (by simply installing it on every node) and Calico as my CNI. No additional configurations were needed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as *default CRI implementation* and *default CNI implementaton*.

It all depends on the Kubernetes distribution you're using.

For example, GKE has its own CNI implementation but nothing prevents you to use Calico.

Comment: If I deploy kubernetes in private cluster, do I need to manually configure CRI and CNI？

Comment: It will depends on your k8s distribution. Are you using kubadm or another distribution ? If you're using a k8s distribution, then everything should be ready to go. If you install all the components one by one, then it will be a bit more touchy.