# why is cri-dockerd needed?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I use Docker version 20.10.22 and Kubernates version 1.25.0-00.

I try to understand kubernetes architecture.

I looked on the web :

- [The differences between Docker, containerd, CRI-O and runc](https://www.tutorialworks.com/difference-docker-containerd-runc-crio-oci/)
- [How Kubernetes creates and runs containers: An illustrated guide](https://www.redhat.com/architect/how-kubernetes-creates-runs-containers)
- [Kubernetes Cluster Setup with Containerd](https://saurabhkharkate05.medium.com/kubernetes-cluster-setup-with-containerd-945214a0d02c)
- [Default CRI implementation and default CNI implementation in K8S](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61748975/default-cri-implementation-and-default-cni-implementation-in-k8s)

I understood that Docker comes with a version of containerd that is not compatible with CRI-O that comes with Kubernates. If I understood correctly this is a question of containerd versions, the one of "docker containerd" is not fully compliant with OCI specification.

Then a plugin is needed to allow Kubernates, *id Kubelet* to interact with the containerd coming with docker.

And this plugin is cri-dockerd.

Is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

Dockershim is no longer a component of the Kubernetes core as of Kubernetes 1.24. Containers built with Docker will continue to function as before. However, users who wish to continue making use of cluster-specific Docker features will need to switch to the cri-dockerd adapter as a result of the change.

Yes, you are right you need to use cri-dockerd instead of dockershim which will be deprecated.You can migrate docker engine nodes from dockershim to cri-dockerd using the following [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/migrating-from-dockershim/migrate-dockershim-dockerd/).

For more understanding attaching a [blog](https://www.mirantis.com/blog/cri-dockerd-faq-blog/) refer to it for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @sai-chandra-gadde but the blog explains "The cri-dockerd adapter is a stable, narrowly scoped, and reliably maintained project to replace the stopgap solution of dockershim". That's mean that kubelet interacts with cri-dockerd which interacts with docker and not containerd. Using the links in the question, I understood that kubelet interacts with CRI-O (or cri-dockerd) to interacts wiht containerd. This is not the same. Do you know what it is ?

Comment: No update ? No one knows the answer ? That's bad ... :) or :(